# Are docker compose networks available to dockerfiles at build time?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

The web server I'm setting up contains a `docker-compose.yml` consisting of a node and postgres service. I am able to talk to the database from the node container using the postgres container's name as a host, once the container is running.

However, I want to integrate database migration logic into the dockerfile for my node service and there the connection fails with the error:

> Could not resolve host: db

This is a simplified version of my configuration to showcase the error:

```yaml
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

## ...Setup...

## Connect to database in order to migrate which essentially does this
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl http://db:5432
# And fails with the above error

## More stuff

# Stage Container
FROM node:18-alpine

# Stuff

## Run application
CMD ["node", "build/index.js"]
```

When accessing the database via `db:5432` from the running container there aren't any issues - but when I try to from the dockerfile, I get the error. Is it just not possible to what I want to do at build time?

Comment: Maybe using [RUN --network](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/dockerfile) but I'm really not sure about that. But I can confirm that it's a bad practice: it's a build, not a deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are docker compose networks available to dockerfiles at build time?

No.

> I want to integrate database migration logic into the dockerfile....  Is it just not possible to what I want to do at build time?

It's not possible.

---

Consider the `postgres` image you're running in the Compose file.  You don't download its Dockerfile and rebuild it from source; instead, you download a precompiled image.  Every Docker image is intended to work this way: in principle you can `docker-compose build && docker-compose push` your built application to some Docker registry, and pull it and run it somewhere else without rebuilding it.

But now, the application data isn't part of your image.  It's stored in the PostgreSQL database, and generally in a named volume that only lives on your machine.  Building a Node application image won't push another container's opaque data along with it.

With that operating model, there are a couple of technical challenges.  The image builder doesn't run on the Compose-provided network, but rather the "default bridge network" that doesn't include some standard Docker features. There's also no ordering constraints between one image building and another running; it'd be normal to `docker-compose build` your application before `docker-compose up` started the database.

---

A typical approach here is to run migrations in an *entrypoint wrapper script*.  Write a shell script which runs migrations and then runs whatever Docker command is passed to it

```bash
#!/bin/sh
npm run migrate
exec "$@"
```

`COPY` this file into the image, make it be the `ENTRYPOINT`, and leave the `CMD` unchanged.

```bash
COPY entrypoint.sh ./  # could be part of COPY ./ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["node", "build/index.js"]
```

This will run migrations on every startup, which is often what you want.

Comment: Thank you! This was beginning to dawn on me as I was writing the question and makes a lot of sense. The ORM I'm using also has the ability to run migrations in the Node app itself. What would you say that using an entrypoint like this is still bad practice and I shouldn't do it, given I could choose not to?

Comment: There's an argument that you should run migrations manually as part of your deploy-to-production sequence.  I think most migration systems can handle having multiple concurrent attempts to migrate.  The big risk is doing something like a Kubernetes rolling update, where you will have both "old" and "new" versions of the software running at the same time, and you need to know which database schema to use.  I don't think doing it in the entrypoint is a bad practice, but it's also not the only way to approach this.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the late reply! I ended up doing it in my web-app in a server-side startup hook which shouldn't be too much of a problem given the size of the project and just makes things a lot easier.